# Debian as VPN Server for Cisco ASR

Tags: debian, vpn, cisco, openvpn, cisco-vpn

I've to set up a Debian Server who should connected by a Cisco ASR via Side2Side VPN with a preshared key. Tried Open-VPN, but found out that both sides need Open-VPN. So the Cisco ASR is the VPN Client and my Debian server is the VPN Server.

Can somephone prefer me a open source software for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Requests for recommendations are not usually on topic here; if you have specific questions about specific open source technologies, it would make for a better question.

Answer (score 0):

The ASR is going to support IPSec, so you'll need to set up an IPSec association between that and your Linux server.